# Independence of a random variable with respect to a sigma field.

Tags: probability-theory, independence

I would like to show that a random variable $X$ is independent of a sigma algebra $\mathcal{G}$ if and only if $$\mathbb{E}[f(X)\mathbb{1}_G]=\mathbb{E}[f(X)]\mathbb{P}(G)$$ for every $f$ bounded measurable.

For the backward direction I noted that taking $f=\mathbb{1}_B$ we have $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\int \mathbb{1}_B(x)\mu_X(dx)=\mu_X(B)=\mathbb{P}(X\in B)$ so the right hand side becomes $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]\mathbb{P}(G)=\mathbb{P}(X\in B)\mathbb{P}(G)$ so I just have to show that the left hand side is equal to $\mathbb{P}(X\in B,G)$.

However $\mathbb{E}[f(X)\mathbb{1}_G]=\int f(X(\omega))\mathbb{1}_G(\omega)\mathbb{P}(d\omega)$ but I am not sure how to apply the change of variable formula. Also I am not sure how to do the forward direction of the proof.

Bonus question : Are there other usual equivalent way of formulating the independence of a random variable with respect to a $\sigma$-field?

Comment: When $f = 1_B$, $f(X) 1_G = 1_{\{X \in B, G\}}$ (multiplying indicator functions is equivalent to taking an intersection of events). For the forwards direction, proving something hold for all bounded measurable functions is almost always done with the monotone class theorem for functions.

Comment: Thank you. For the monotone class theorem I guess you take the multiplicative system to be $\{1_B: B\text{ measurable}\}$ and the linear space $\mathcal{H}=\{f \text{ bounded} : E[f(X)1_G]=E[f(X)]P(G)\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an equivalent way to formulate the independence between $\sigma(X)$ and $\mathcal{G}$:

> $\sigma(X)$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are independent iff for every $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable $Z$ and every bounded measurable functions $f$ and $g$
> $$
> \mathsf{E} f(X)g(Z)=\mathsf{E}f(X)\mathsf{E}g(Z).
> $$

When $\sigma(X)$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are independent, approximating $f$ and $g$ by sequences of simple functions gives the result. Conversely, take $f=1_B$, $Z=1_G$, and $g(z)=z^{+}\wedge 1$, where $B$ is a Borel set and $G\in\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Thank you. This makes me think of a "third" equivalent way of formulating independence. $X$ independent of $\mathcal{G}$ iff $X$ independent of $Z$ for every $Z$ which is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. Forward direction : $P(X\in A, \underbrace{Z\in B}_{\in\mathcal{G}})=P(X\in A)P(Z\in B)$. Converse direction : $P(X\in A, G)=P(X\in A,1_G\in\{1\})=P(X\in A)P(1_G\in\{1\})=P(X\in A)P(G)$ since $1_G$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.